# Does Konsole permit launching a terminal with a custom font-size on the command-line?

Tags: configuration, fonts, arguments, konsole

If I want to launch a Konsole can I do so with a font-size of 30px rather than the default?

Comment: Probably not - the KDE developers are dead set against that, *per se*.  You can create a profile and reference that (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48668068/can-properties-like-color-and-font-be-set-on-konsole-command-line)).

Comment: @ThomasDickey if you want to make that an answer, i'll accept it (pending a better solution).

Comment: It seem there is a -p option to do what you want. See https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/applications/konsole/command-line-options.html .

Comment: @ctac_ I'm using that elsewhere, I just didn't see any profile options that altered font size. Give it a shot.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this by editing the current profile, and then using that file to get the correct property value.

Edit Current Profile...-> Appearance -> Select Font... (Set to whatever you like) -> Apply

For this example I used:

- Font: Courier 10 Pitch
- Font style: Regular
- Size: 30.0

Look in the file to view the new property:

```
~/.kde/share/apps/konsole/YourProfileName.profile
```

Here we see the custom property:

```
Font=Courier 10 Pitch,12,-1,5,50,0,0,0,0,0
```

Now from the command line, launch with this property

```
konsole -p Font="Courier 10 Pitch,30,-1,5,50,0,0,0,0,0"
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not - the KDE developers are dead set against that, *per se*. You can create a profile and reference that (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48668068/can-properties-like-color-and-font-be-set-on-konsole-command-line)).

As noted in a followup comment, if you happen to *know* the name of the relevant property, you can override that on the command-line for a given profile, as hinted in the [documentation](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/applications/konsole/command-line-options.html) using **`-p`**:

> **`-p`** *property=value*
>
> Change the value of a profile property.

These options help find the name:

> **`--list-profiles`**

```
List all available profiles.
```

> **`--list-profile-properties`**

```
List all possible properties with name and type. See option -p.

For more information, please visit [Konsole API Reference][3].
```

But the API reference does not list font **size** by itself, only the property for [**font**](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qfont.html).  You would have to add a [*pixelSize*](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qfont.html#pixelSize) or [*pointSize*](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qfont.html#pointSize) to that.